# Proof for $\Gamma\Big(x+\frac{1}{2}\Big)^2 < x\Gamma(x)^2$

Tags: gamma-function

I've encountered the following inequality which I am not able to prove but pretty certain that it is true:
$$\Gamma\Big(x+\frac{1}{2}\Big)^2 < x\Gamma(x)^2$$
This should be true for $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$. However, I only need this for $x\in\mathbb{Q}^{+}$ or even $x=\frac{n}{4}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$, so I can prove
$$\Gamma\Big(\frac{k+7}{4}\Big)^2 < \frac{k+5}{4}\Gamma\Big(\frac{k+5}{4}\Big)^2$$
and similar expressions for $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

In general, I have trouble with terms involving $\Gamma\Big(x+\frac{1}{2}\Big)$. I am aware of Gautschi's Inequality, but find it not quite sharp enough for small $x$. So I would also be thankful for any information on inequalities for $\Gamma\Big(x+\frac{1}{2}\Big)$.

Thanks,
Nils

Comment: Just use the functional equation for $\Gamma$ and log-convexity.

Comment: [Gautschi’s Inequality](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.6.E4) works just fine. Take $s=1/2$, then $$
x^{1/2}  < \frac{{\Gamma (x + 1)}}{{\Gamma (x + 1/2)}} = \frac{{x\Gamma (x)}}{{\Gamma (x + 1/2)}}
$$ for $x>0$. Re-arrange to get $$
\Gamma (x + 1/2) < x^{1/2} \Gamma (x)
$$ for $x>0$. The inequality cannot be true for all real $x$ due to the poles of the gamma function.

Comment: @Gary Thanks! And I've also meant $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$ and edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Gautschi's Inequality](http://dlmf.nist.gov/5.6.E4) works just fine. Take $s=1/2$, then
$$x^{1/2}  < \frac{{\Gamma (x + 1)}}{{\Gamma (x + 1/2)}} = \frac{{x\Gamma (x)}}{{\Gamma (x + 1/2)}}$$
for $x>0$. Re-arrange to get
$$\Gamma (x + 1/2) < x^{1/2} \Gamma (x)$$
for $x>0$.